# How to understand the trick in MNIST experiments using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a beginner for Tensorflow. I am a bit confused by the tutorial. The author firstly gives a formula y=softmax(Wx+b), but use xW+b in the python code and explain it is a small trick. I do not understand the trick, why does the author need to flip the formula?

> https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners
>
> First, we multiply x by W with the expression tf.matmul(x, W). This is
>   flipped from when we multiplied them in our equation, where we had Wx,
>   as a small trick to deal with x being a 2D tensor with multiple
>   inputs. We then add b, and finally apply tf.nn.softmax.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the formula,

```
y=softmax(Wx + b)
```

[image]

the input x is multiplied by the Weight variable W,but in the doc

```
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
```

**W is multiplied by x for calculation convenience**, so we must flip W from 10*784 to 784*10 keep consistent with the formula.

Answer (score 1):

In general in machine learning, esp. tensorflow, *you always want your first dimension to represent your batch*. The trick is only a way of ensuring that without transposing everything before and after each matrix multiplication.

`x` is not really a column vector of features, but a 2D matrix of shape `(batch_size, n_features)`.

If you keep `Wx`, then you'll transpose `x` (to `x'` of shape `(n_features, batch_size)`) use `W` of shape `(n_outputs, n_features)`, and `Wx'` will be of shape `(n_outputs, batch_size)`, so you'll have to transpose it back to `(batch_size, n_outputs)`, which is what you want in the end.

If you're using `tf.matmul(x, W)`, then `W` is of shape `(n_features, n_outputs )`, and the result is directly of shape `(batch_size, n_outputs)`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is not clear at first.

> `x` being a 2D tensor with multiple inputs

is a very succinct way to tell you that in tensorflow, data is stored in tensors following conventions that are not those of linear algebra.

In particular, the outermost dimension (i.e. columns for matrices) is always the sample dimension: that is, it has the same size as your number of samples.

When you store sample features in a 2D tensor (a matrix), the features are therefore stored in the inner-most dimension, i.e. lines. That is, tensor `x` is the transposed of variable $x$ in the equation. So are `W` and `b`. The fact that `x.T*W.T=(W.x).T` explains the swap inconsistency in the multiplication between the linear algebra equation and the tensor implementation of it.